# PYGame - ImportError: No module named locals Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi

I have the following code:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 # -*- coding: iso-8859-15 -*-

 import pygame, random
 from pygame.locals import *
 pygame.init()
 clock = pygame.time.Clock()

 and so on
```

The app all appears OK, but when I compile the code I get the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "fish.py", line 4, in <module>
import pygame, random
 File "/home/pi/pygame/pygame.py", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named locals


------------------
(program exited with code: 1)
Press return to continue
```

Can anyone help? I'm new to Python and Linux.

I've done the following:

```
 pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo apt-get install python-pygame
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 python-pygame is already the newest version.
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
 pi@raspberrypi:~$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you have a file that is named `pygame.py`, or a bytecode left-over from such a file named `pygame.pyc`.

---

Calling `import pygame` works, but it will not import pygame, but the that very file.

And since your file can't find a module named `locals` in that file, the error is raised.

So, just rename your file to anything other than `pygame.py` or other modules you want to import, or, if there's a  `pygame.pyc` bytecode file, remove that.

Comment: er its not its called fish.py

Comment: The error you posted says `"/home/pi/pygame/pygame.py"`, so I guess your file is called `pygame.py` and is in the directory `/home/pi/pygame`.

Comment: @WelshKing So you have *another* file in your directory which is called `pygame.py`

Comment: The file is called fish.py " Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "fish.py", line 4, in <module> " I have no idea what pygame.py is, I thought that was part of the compiler ?

Comment: @WelshKing But what is `/home/pi/pygame/pygame.py`?

Comment: when i use a terminal to go to/home/pi/pygame it is not a directory ? As I said before Im new to Python and Linux

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15325/discussion-between-bigyellowcactus-and-welsh-king)

Comment: No worries - I think the problem started when they downloaded MagPi tbh.

Answer (score 0):

Try using IDLE instead of IDLE 3. It worked for me and I had exactly the same problem shown above.