# ImportError: cannot import name Thread

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x

It's my first time to learn python, and I went ahead to try threading from [this blog post](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/09/simplistic-python-thread-example/). The problem is it seems to be outdated:

```
import time
from threading import Thread

def myfunc(i):
    print ("sleeping 5 sec from thread %d" % i)
    time.sleep(5)
    print ("finished sleeping from thread %d" % i)

for i in range(10):
    t = Thread(target=myfunc, args=(i,))
    t.start()
```

How do I run this code without having this error:

```
$ python helloworld.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 1, in <module>
    import threading
  File "c:\Documents and Settings\Hermione\learningPython\threading.py", line 2, in <module>
    from threading import Thread
ImportError: cannot import name Thread
```

It's also weird that I have `threading.py` there for the fact that **I already deleted that file** (and it keeps appearing!!), and a mysterious `__PyCache__` folder.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your problem is that you *once had* a file called `threading.py`, which probably left a byte-code file called threading.pyc.

You have to delete it also.

Similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11949200/pygame-importerror-no-module-named-locals-rasberry-pi).

**EDIT:** Realising that you are using python3, delete the [`__pycache__`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/) directory as well (this is where the file resides using python3.2 and later).

Answer (score 12):

You've named your file `threading.py` which hides the standard library module by the same name. .. don't do that :-)

Comment: but I have deleted that file. And as you can see it's now named `helloworld.py`

Comment: Seems it finds this one: ` File "c:\Documents and Settings\Hermione\learningPython\threading.py"`

Comment: You can always try `import threading; print(threading.__file__)` to figure out whence it finds the `threading` module that it imports.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete threading.pyc as well as the threading.py file, or if you are using Python 3.2, the `__pycache__` directory.