# Error occuring when importing module "threading"

Tags: python, python-3.x

In a project I need to import RLock from threading module in Python3.6
But no matter what I do, I still have the same error :

```py
from threading import RLock
```

```sh
ImportError: cannot import name 'RLock'
```

Each time I want to import this module **(threading)** I have this error.

I already upgraded pip, but it doesn't work.

If someone has a solution for me I would be very grateful.

### Edit

This error doesn't depend on the folder in which I am located. I notice that when I am running the command in Python2.7 :

```py
import threading
```

It works. 
But if I am running this command under Python3.6 it doesn't work, still with the same output error.

I checked and the only threading.py files I have are :

```
/snap/core/6673/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py
/snap/core/6818/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py
/snap/core/6964/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py
/snap/core18/941/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py
/snap/core18/970/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py
/snap/docker/384/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py
/snap/docker/384/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py
/snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/36/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py
/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/40/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py
/snap/libxml2/69/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py
/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc
/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py
/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py
```

Comment: Could be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051895/importerror-cannot-import-name-thread our case?

Comment: Do you have any file called `threading.py`?. If so, that is the source of your problem. Change it to some other name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked, but unfortunately there are no file named threading in the project

Comment: Did you try deleting `__pycache__` ([as per the first answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12051962/10239789))?

Comment: Do you know your which path is used by your Python? (Python2 and 3) I think your Python uses a path where the threading module is not available.

Comment: You can try to add this line to your file before import: `sys.path.append("/usr/lib/python3.6")` In this case your Python will find the files in this folder as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the origin of the problem by looking at the complete error logs (which I should have specified here, I apologize). Turns out I have a file named **token.py**. By renaming it the error disappears.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a Python file which called threading. You should rename your file and the import will work. I have just tried it with Python3.6.6 and it works as expected.

Code

```
from threading import RLock

rl = RLock()

print(rl)
```

Output:

```
>>>python other.py 
<_RLock owner=None count=0>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I checked and unfortunately I don't have any threading file in this project. I just edited my post !